# $\sqrt[3]{e^{i\pi}} \;{ \stackrel {?}{=} }-1$

Tags: complex-numbers

$e^{i\pi}=-1$

then if we take the cube root shouldn't the answer for $e^{i\pi/3}=-1$ as well? Since the cube root of -1 is -1.

If so why is the above=$1/2+i\sqrt3/2$ ?

Comment: $(-2)^2=4$. Then if we take the square root shouldn't we get $-2=2$? Since the square root of 4 is 2.

Comment: @GerryMyerson : $(-2)^2=2^2$, $\sqrt{(-2)^2}=\sqrt{2^2}$ order of operation matters otherwise we do end up with $-2=2$ rather than $\sqrt 4 = \sqrt 4 = 2$, I think somehow making order of operation explicitly visible would stop similar type of confusions, not sure how I can make the order of operations explicitly stated.

Comment: Yup got it. Was really careless.

Answer (score 1):

> Since the cube root of $-1$ is $-1$.

This is wrong. The cube root of $-1$ has $3$ values: one real, $-1$ and two complex $\frac12 \pm i \frac{\sqrt3}{2}$.